# Azure AD missing Attribute

Tags: azure, entra-id

I have setup an application my company is developing with Azure AD and i'm trying to customize the Claims to send, but i'm missing the "Attributes" tab. I do see it if i add an application from the catalog but not when i do a customized one. Any one know how to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution via the old Azure Portal (manage.windowsazure.com) which I assume only works if you have an Azure Active Directory Premium subscription;

Active Directory, Choose a Directory (in my case: default directory), Applications Tab, click 'Add' (down the bottom of the window), Add an application from the Gallery, select 'Custom' from the list on the left, type your app's name (i.e. Alex's Company App), click the tick icon.

At this point you should see 'Alex's Company App has been added' and the Attributes Tab, Click 'Configure single sign on' and follow the prompts from there.

I agree it was hard to find. Took me at least 4 hours over two days :b